# GWT Google Maps: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I'm using GWT (version 2.61) and gwt-maps (version 3.8.0) in an effort to display a Google Map via GWT.

The basics seem to work, but now I'm trying to run the CitySimple example that comes with the gwt-maps zip. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple) it is in straight JavaScript, but I'm trying to do it through GWT.

However, when I run the sample, I get the following error upon startup:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (InvalidValueError) @com.google.maps.gwt.client.Circle::create(Lcom/google/maps/gwt/client/CircleOptions;)([JavaScript object(17)]): setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.maps.gwt.client.Circle$.create(Circle.java)
    at com.test.client.GwtTest.renderMap(GwtTest.java:80)
```

The map shows up, but none of the city circles show up. It seems to believe that the lat value in my LatLng type is not a number, which is impossible in GWT, since Java will *only* take a double value.

Here is the GWT code I'm running:

```
package com.test.client;

import java.util.HashMap;

import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader;
import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader.AjaxLoaderOptions;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.Circle;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.CircleOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.GoogleMap;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeId;

public class GwtTest implements EntryPoint {

    static class City {
        LatLng center;
        Long population;

        City(LatLng center, Long population) {
            this.center = center;
            this.population = population;
        }
    }

    private static java.util.Map<String, City> citymap = new HashMap<String, City>();
    static {
        citymap.put("Chicago", new City(LatLng.create(41.878113, -87.629798), 2842518L));
        citymap.put("New York", new City(LatLng.create(40.714352, -74.005973), 8143197L));
        citymap.put("Los Angeles", new City(LatLng.create(34.052234, -118.243684), 3844829L));
    }

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
        options.setOtherParms("sensor=false");
        Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                renderMap();
            }
        };
        AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
    }

    public static void renderMap() {
        MapOptions mapOpts = MapOptions.create();
        mapOpts.setZoom(4);
        mapOpts.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mapOpts.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        GoogleMap map = GoogleMap.create(Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOpts);

        for (String cityName : citymap.keySet()) {

            System.out.println("City: " + cityName);

            City city = citymap.get(cityName);

            // Construct the circle for each value in citymap. Scale population by 20.
            CircleOptions populationOptions = CircleOptions.create();
            populationOptions.setStrokeColor("#ff0000");
            populationOptions.setStrokeOpacity(0.8);
            populationOptions.setStrokeWeight(2);
            populationOptions.setFillColor("#ff0000");
            populationOptions.setFillOpacity(0.35);
            populationOptions.setMap(map);

            System.out.println("Lat: " + city.center.lat());
            System.out.println("Lng: " + city.center.lng());

            populationOptions.setCenter(city.center);

            populationOptions.setRadius(city.population / 20);
            Circle.create(populationOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, all of the LatLng values have numbers for their lats and lngs, so this error doesn't make any sense to me.

For completeness, here is my html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">                                               
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="GwtTest.css">                               
    <title>GWT Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
        src="gwttest/gwttest.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Testing</p>
    <div style="width:500px; height:500px">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Map is loading...</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my GWT module xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.6.1//EN"
  "file:///C:/Users/kworkman/Desktop/gwt-2.6.1/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='gwttest'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name="com.google.maps.gwt.GoogleMaps" />
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.AjaxLoader" />

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='com.test.client.GwtTest'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

Can anybody see anything I'm doing wrong? I'm still brand new to GWT so I wouldn't be shocked if I was doing something stupid, but this error seems to directly contradict the code, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

I have googled the error, but every problem I've seen was caused by people passing in Strings instead of numbers to the LatLng type, which I'm not doing.

Comment: You download the maps api twice: one time in your html file (<script...), and one more time with AjaxLoader.loadApi. Maybe try to remove the one in the html file.

Comment: @philfr49 Thanks for pointing that out. I still don't really know what I'm doing here, so every little pointer helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code using LatLng type is executed BEFORE the api is loaded.
Try to initialize your citymap object once the api is fully loaded:

```
Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       citymap.put("Chicago", new City(LatLng.create(41.878113, -87.629798), 2842518L));
       citymap.put("New York", new City(LatLng.create(40.714352, -74.005973), 8143197L));
       citymap.put("Los Angeles", new City(LatLng.create(34.052234, -118.243684), 3844829L));

       renderMap();
    }
};
```

This is because the LatLng object is of type JavaScriptObject and will use javascript functions from the api.

Also see my comment about you loading the api twice.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks so much!